# T-SQL Replacing If Else (Case When) with lookup table

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-server-2012, lookup, case-when

*edit

As pointed out my question provided the neccessary details. So I will try to be precise.

The bloated If Else structure is used in a crystal report. The result is a csv export. This is the way it works now. :) The design decission was to rework this and generate dynamic SQL. So that these bloated If Else structures will become part of a SQL query.

Right now I've implemented a modell to be able to create T-SQL dynamically. I've come up with a table that holds the column definitions for the Select part of the query, a table that holds the join conditions and a table that holds the where conditions. In a stored procedure all the information is gathered and a T-SQl query is the result.

SELECT Column Definition Table:

```
ColumnName  T-SQL                           OrderID IncludeInSelectList InterfaceID_ID
Monat       SUBSTRING(CP.TCOEP_PERIO, 2,2)  1       1                   1
Jahr        CP.TCOEP_GJAHR                  2       1                   1
```

The problem is that in the table with the column definition the column that will store the SQL definition (e.g. Substring(ColA, 2,3)) has the max length restriction of 4000 characters.

The more I'm trying to explain it, the more I'm getting the feeling that trying to get everything into one giant query isn't a good idea at all. I have to speak to my superior I guess. ;)
*edit

I'm having troubles replacing a bloated If Else structure. Here is an example:

```
If ColA startswith 'ABC' then 'Ext' else
If ColB startswith 'DBC' then 'Int' else
If ColC startswith ('CCC', 'DDD','EEE', ..) then 'N/A'
```

.... and so on.

I know I can rewrite this into a Case When structure. The problem is that this needs to be stored in a table where the max length is nvarchar(4000). I tried to solve this with a lookup table looking like this:

lookupColumnName | lookupValue | lookupResultName | lookupResult

I was trying to write my query in a more "generic" way like:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT lookupResult from lookupTable where lookupColumn = 'ColA')
FROM
SourceTable
```

Here is my first try to implement the order of the origanel If Else structure:

```
CASE WHEN
    CASE WHEN
        CASE WHEN 
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) IS NULL THEN (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'XBLNR' AND BKPF_XBLNR like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC
        ) ELSE (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) END 
        <> 'LEER' THEN
        CASE WHEN 
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) IS NULL THEN (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'XBLNR' AND BKPF_XBLNR like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC
        ) ELSE (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) END
        ELSE
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'SGTXT' AND COEP_SGTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC
        )
    END IS NULL THEN 'App'
    ELSE
    CASE WHEN
        CASE WHEN 
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) IS NULL THEN (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'XBLNR' AND BKPF_XBLNR like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC
        ) ELSE (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) END 
        <> 'LEER' THEN
        CASE WHEN 
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) IS NULL THEN (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'XBLNR' AND BKPF_XBLNR like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC
        ) ELSE (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' AND BKPF_BKTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC 
        ) END
        ELSE
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult FROM ##lookupDefinition where lookupColumnName = 'SGTXT' AND COEP_SGTXT like lookupValue order by len(lookupValue) DESC
        )
    END
END
```

But this approach could also result in a string containing more than 4000 characters.

Right now I'm stuck. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm afraid, that your edits did not make things much better ;-) It would help to set up a SQL Fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) with the actual table's structures, some sample data and what you've tried. Then poste the expected output.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've combined both suggestions yours and the one from GarethD. I'm very pleased with the result. Thank You!!!!

Comment: Glad to read, that you could solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty difficult to follow your exact logic, since it is pretty complicated and not helped by the fact that no columns have table aliases so I don't know what column belongs to what table.

I have however given it a go. Since you are reusing the same correlated subquery multiple times, it would probably be beneficial to move these to an APPLY so that the result can be reused. I then just tried to pick apart your logic replacing the statements like:

```
CASE WHEN <expression1> IS NULL THEN <expression2> ELSE <expression1> END
```

With

```
ISNULL(<expression1>, <expression2>)
```

Giving a final query of:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN ISNULL(BKTXT.LookupResult, XBLNR.LookupResult) <> 'LEER' THEN
            ISNULL(BKTXT.LookupResult, XBLNR.LookupResult)
        ELSE 
            ISNULL(SGTXT.LookupResult, 'App')
        END         
FROM    SourceTable
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult 
            FROM ##lookupDefinition 
            WHERE lookupColumnName = 'BKTXT' 
            AND COEP_SGTXT LIKE lookupValue 
            ORDER BY LEN(lookupValue) DESC
        ) AS BKTXT
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult 
            FROM ##lookupDefinition 
            WHERE lookupColumnName = 'XBLNR' 
            AND COEP_SGTXT LIKE lookupValue 
            ORDER BY LEN(lookupValue) DESC
        ) AS XBLNR
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT TOP 1 lookupResult 
            FROM ##lookupDefinition 
            WHERE lookupColumnName = 'SGTXT' 
            AND COEP_SGTXT LIKE lookupValue 
            ORDER BY LEN(lookupValue) DESC
        ) AS SGTXT;
```

Comment: Haven't thought of using cross apply yet. Thank you

Comment: I like this approach. Maybe the OP wants to combine yours and my suggestion with an UDF could make it even easier. +1 from my side

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to use a "more generic" way, pushed me to this idea:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLookUp(@LookupColumnName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal VARCHAR(100)='#missing value!!!';
    SELECT lookupResult from lookupTable where lookupColumn = @LookupColumnName;
    RETURN @RetVal;
END
```

Your

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT lookupResult from lookupTable where lookupColumn = 'ColA')
FROM
SourceTable
```

Is transfered to

```
SELECT dbo.GetLookUp('ColA')
FROM
SourceTable
```

That would mean you save a lot of characters.

But I must admit that the whole concept is not clear to me and there is quite some smell of to much complexity. Maybe you want to give details about your table structures, some sample data and expected output.

I'm quite sure, that there is some better approach...

Comment: could really be a way to save up characters